# AspNet WebApi POST parameter is null when sending XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api service originally using beta bits which I've rebuilt using the release candidate bits and I'm now having this problem.

I have a POST action that takes a complex option as the only parameter.  When I send the request with the body in json format the object is deserialised as expected, but if I send XML instead the parameter is null.

In the beta I worked around this by disabling model binding as described in Carlos Figueira's blog post [Disabling model binding on ASP.NET Web APIs Beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/27/disabling-model-binding-on-asp-net-web-apis-beta.aspx)

In the RC however they have removed the IRequestContentReadPolicy that this method was implementing.

My action:

```
public List<Models.Payload> Post([FromBody]Models.AimiRequest requestValues)
{
  try
  {
    if (requestValues == null)
    {
      var errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
      errorResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
      errorResponse.Content = new StringContent("parameter 'request' is null");
      throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
    }
    var metadataParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (Models.MetadataQueryParameter param in requestValues.Metadata)
    {
      metadataParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(param.Name, param.Value));
    }
    List<Core.Data.Payload> data = _payloadService.FindPayloads(metadataParams, requestValues.ContentType, requestValues.RuleTypes);
    var retVal = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Core.Data.Payload>, List<Models.Payload>>(data);
    return retVal; // new HttpResponseMessage<List<Models.Payload>>(retVal);
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    _logger.RaiseError(ex);
    throw;
  }
}
```

My model:

```
public class AimiRequest
{
  public MetadataQueryParameter[] Metadata { get; set; }
  public string ContentType { get; set; }
  public string RuleTypes { get; set; }
}

public class MetadataQueryParameter
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm testing using Fiddler to send requests to the service.

This works and returns me the expected results.

```
POST http://localhost:51657/api/search HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:51657
Content-Length: 219

{
  "ContentType":null,
  "RuleTypes":null,
  "Metadata":[
    {
    "Name":"ClientName",
    "Value":"Client One"
    },
    {
    "Name":"ClientName",
    "Value":"Client Two"
    }
  ]
}
```

This fails because the requestValues parameter is null

```
POST http://localhost:51657/api/search HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/xml
Host: localhost:51657
Content-Length: 213

<AimiRequest>
  <ContentType />
  <RuleTypes />
  <Metadata>
    <MetadataQueryParameter>
      <Name>ClientName</Name>
      <Value>Client One</Value>
    </MetadataQueryParameter>
    <MetadataQueryParameter>
      <Name>ClientName</Name>
      <Value>Client Two</Value>
    </MetadataQueryParameter>
  </Metadata>
</AimiRequest>
```

Comment: See details in this [question][1]...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068288/model-always-null-on-xml-post

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By adding the following lines to the ApplicationStart() method in your
Global.asax.cs, your original XML request should work:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

By default, the Web API uses the DataContractSerializer class, which requires extra information in the XML request.

The XmlSerializer seems to work more smoothly for me, since I don't have to add the model's namepsace to each XML request.

Once again, i found my information in Mike Wasson's article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter

Comment: this was the solution I was looking for. I had the same problem where json would work fine, but object would always be null when using xml

Comment: not working for me. now the app is returning "The request entity's media type 'application/xml' is not supported for this resource.".

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem as you, and found the solution by serializing the object using the XmlMediaTypeFormatter as described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#testing_object_serialization. I used the code in the "Testing Object Serialization" section at the bottom of the article, and replaced his Person object with my model.

When I serialized my object, I noticed that the following attributes were added to the root node:

```
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NAMESPACE.OF.YOUR.MODEL"
```

If you add these attributes to your xml like so, your controller should correctly serialize the requestValues object:

```
<AimiRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NAMESPACE.OF.YOUR.MODEL">
  <ContentType />
  <RuleTypes />
  <Metadata>
    <MetadataQueryParameter>
      <Name>ClientName</Name>
      <Value>Client One</Value>
    </MetadataQueryParameter>
    <MetadataQueryParameter>
      <Name>ClientName</Name>
      <Value>Client Two</Value>
    </MetadataQueryParameter>
  </Metadata>
</AimiRequest>
```