# Web API Post parameters are always Null

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api

did anybody find a proper resolution of this? 
I just tried with WebAPI in big hopes (after completing a successful implementation of rest api in php/restler with KO and HTML5). Get is working like charm. Got stuck in post for last 20+ hours as no matter what always my variable is null. I do have DTO and repository implementation which is part of my framework anyway. 
I tried with FromBody hint and pretty much everything available in my search.
I am testing this using CRest and Fiddler.
I am even fine with getting raw request.content and then will deal with json loading etc by myself. 
This point I am just frustrated and thinking about moving back to 4.0 and use wcf to generate ResT again.
Any help would be really appreciated ...

```
DTO:
public class TestEntity
{
    public TestEntity() { } 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:
public class testController : ApiController

```
{
    // POST api/test
    public TestEntity PostTest([FromBody] TestEntity t)
    {
        var x = new TestEntity();
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return x;
        }
        else
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

I am invoking thru CREST ....

Comment: Using your code and invoking it through Fiddler works for me with both XML and JSON. You can rule out a routing issue by adding a GET method to the controller that returns a your TestEntity with some test data and invoking that. If that works, copy the data it returned into Fiddler as your POST request body and see if t gets populated. That will rule out a serialization issue. If it still fails, try posting the full controller code, along with the URL and data you're inputting in Fiddler to test with.

Comment: In fiddler I get:
{"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'TestEntity' from content with media type ''undefined''.","StackTrace":"   

When I run in CRest it actually go run the specific method (I can debug) and the value of the param is null

Comment: Update:
After changing Content-Type to json, it is now working. 
I am surprised why it was not working through CRest which I used extensively in previous project (services created through restler 2 in php 5). Also I shall check how it will work with json created through KnockoutJS

Comment: Now as I invoke the api from my html5 page I still get null. Client code is:


` $.ajax({
                    datatype: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:9361/api/controllername',
                    data: { data: ko.toJSON(vmModelName) },
`

Comment: Resolved - it was a small mismatch in javascript !

Comment: Readers of this can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142702/aspnet-webapi-post-parameter-is-null-when-sending-xml

Comment: @pagladasu your small mismatch was, I would guess, the use of the redundant "data" property within the data parameter? Also, and more importantly, could you post your "changed the content-type to json" as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue came when you calling api using xml type i think,

Web API using Json Serializer in default hence your application working after you changing the content-type to JSON.

See the below code and add this to your WebApiConfig.cs , it is using to handle XML type request.

config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;

And call again your service.It will fix this issues.