# MVC4 Web API Post Parameter Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

[Web API Post parameters are always Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690514/web-api-post-parameters-are-always-null)

[ASP.NET Web API POST parameter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035849/asp-net-web-api-post-parameter-is-null)

What worked for these folks, doesn't seem to be working for me. I have almost exactly the same setup but still getting null in my second controller. The first one works just fine, but I can't replicate it in a second controller.

API Call

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:52441/api/login",
    data: { "Username": "test", "Password": "ptest" }
})
.done(function (data) {
    //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Controller class

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    public bool Post([FromBody]Creds creds)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Creds class

```
public class Creds
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Creds(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.Username = user;
        this.Password = pass;
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works inside of another controller (UsersController). When I pass `{ "First_Name": "John", "Last_Name": "Doe" }` I properly receive a User object in the Post method `public void Post([FromBody]User user)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to web-api, but it would certainly fail for mvc because you do not have a parameterless constructor for `Creds`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the reply! I will set one up, but in my original post, I mentioned I have a User class as well, and it's setup exactly the same, and it works. Also, I'm not sure if that would explain why my post params are null?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Holy crap! I apologize I didn't believe you. I threw one in just to see, and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the modified code below:

API Call:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:52441/api/login/validate",
    data: { "Username": "test", "Password": "ptest" }
})
.done(function (data) {
    //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Controller class:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Validate(Creds creds)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Creds class:

Unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, no go on that. It was what StephenMuecke suggested. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below Code

Web API
Controller class

```
   public class LoginController : ApiController
        {
            public bool Validate([FromUri]Creds creds)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Creds class

```
public class Creds
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Creds(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.Username = user;
        this.Password = pass;
    }
}
```

Either Use API Ajax call in the following manner

```
var RequestZipCode = { Username: "test", Password: "ptest" };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: Creds,
                url: "api/Name of the Controller/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data){
                    ShowData(data);
            }
            });
```

Create a client application that will call webapi in the following manner

```
StringBuilder sbAPIRequest = new StringBuilder();
 sbAPIRequest.Append("?Username=test");
                sbAPIRequest.Append("&Password=ptest");

                HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sbAPIRequest.ToString());

                httpWReq.Method = "GET";
                httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
                httpWReq.ContentLength = 0;

                HttpWebResponse Httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
                string responseString = new StreamReader(Httpresponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

@StephenMuecke had the correct answer for me. It was because my class had a parameterless constructor.

I needed to do this to my Creds class

```
public class Creds
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Creds()
    {
        this.Username = string.Empty;
        this.Password = string.Empty;
    }

    public Creds(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.Username = user;
        this.Password = pass;
    }
}
```

Big thank you to @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a model to take multi post parameters. You can use dynamic object instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public SomeObject GetSomeObject([FromBody] dynamic postData) {
    var a = postData.[property name];
}
```