# Web Api Post value is always null when using Chrome Postman Plugin

Tags: xml, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I'm following an example here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations but I'm having trouble getting it to receive a post request from the chrome postman plugin.

Here's an example of the xml I'm posting. I have set the Content-Type header in Postman to application/xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Product>
  <Category>Groceries</Category>
  <Name>New From Post</Name>
  <Price>1.39</Price>
</Product>
```

I have also tried the following solution [Model always null on XML POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068288/model-always-null-on-xml-post) but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Here's my WebApiConfig file.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I'm definitely hitting the right end point and I can see when I debug it that item is null.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
        {
            item = repository.Add(item);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Also this seems to work ok when I post the same values with json. I really need to be able to test this with xml though.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `DataContract` like so, to your DTO class.

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, send the right namespace info.

Comment: Don't forget to add the [DataMember] attributes to the properties, otherwise they won't get deserialized also.