# Deserialize Nested XML with Web Api MVC 4

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following XML which I am attempting to deserialize to an order object with MVC 4 Web Api with .Net Framework 4.5... but when I send this XML using POST from Chrome Advanced Rest Client with Content-Type set to application/xml the order data is null at the server (It does appear to work if I send the sample xml generated by the Web Api Help page). How can I deserialize the original xml without changing it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <order>
    <header>
        <organization id="1"></organization>
        <customerClient id=""></customerClient>
        <date>05/06/14</date>
        <customerOrderNumber>123-4567-8901</customerOrderNumber>
        <number>abc-1234</number>
                <OriginalNumber></OriginalNumber>
                <status id="0"></status>
        <billing-info>
            <name>A Person</name>
            <address1>123 Main Street</address1>
            <address2></address2>
            <city>Cityville</city>
            <state>AK</state>
            <zip>55555</zip>
            <country>US</country>
            <phone>5555551212</phone>
            <emailAddress>aperson@gmail.com</emailAddress>
            <cc number="" exp="" ccv="" amt=""></cc>
        </billing-info>
    </header>
    <data>
        <shipments>
            <shipment>
                <shipping-info>
                    <name>A Person</name>
                    <address1>123 Main Street</address1>
                    <address2></address2>
                    <city>Cityville</city>
                    <state>AK</state>
                    <zip>55555</zip>
                    <country>US</country>
                    <phone></phone>
                    <emailAddress>aperson@gmail.com</emailAddress>
                    <method>13</method>
                    <shipCharge>2.00</shipCharge>
                </shipping-info>
                <gift-note></gift-note>
                <ship-attributes></ship-attributes>
                <products>
                    <line-item number="1">
                        <mc_order></mc_order>
                        <sku>ABC123</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                        <description></description>
                        <images>
                            <image no="1">
                                <url>http://pictures.com/123/page1.jpg</url>
                            </image>
                            <image no="2">
                                <url>http://pictures.com/123/page1.jpg</url>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                        <attributes>
                            <attribute id="123"></attribute>
                        </attributes>
                    </line-item>
                </products>
            </shipment>
        </shipments>
    </data>
</order>
```

The XML schema is set in stone I am not allowed to modify it.

I have pasted XML As Classes to my Web Api project in Visual Studio 2012 and it created this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MyProject.Models
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class order
    {

        private orderHeader headerField;

        private orderData dataField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public orderHeader header
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headerField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public orderData data
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dataField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class orderHeader
    {

        private orderHeaderOrganization organizationField;

        private orderHeaderCustomerClient customerClientField;

        private string dateField;

        private string customerOrderNumberField;

        private string numberField;

        private object originalNumberField;

        private orderHeaderStatus statusField;

        private orderHeaderBillinginfo billinginfoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public orderHeaderOrganization organization
        {
            get
            {
                return this.organizationField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.organizationField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public orderHeaderCustomerClient customerClient
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerClientField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerClientField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string date
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string customerOrderNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerOrderNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerOrderNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string number
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.numberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object OriginalNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.originalNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.originalNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public orderHeaderStatus status
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.statusField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("billing-info")]
        public orderHeaderBillinginfo billinginfo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.billinginfoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.billinginfoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class orderHeaderOrganization
    {

        private byte idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class orderHeaderCustomerClient
    {

        private string idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class orderHeaderStatus
    {

        private byte idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class orderHeaderBillinginfo
    {

        private string nameField;

        private string address1Field;

        private object address2Field;

        private string cityField;

        private string stateField;

        private ushort zipField;

        private string countryField;

        private ulong phoneField;

        private string emailAddressField;

        private orderHeaderBillinginfoCC ccField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string address1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.address1Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.address1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public object address2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.address2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.address2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string city
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cityField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string state
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort zip
        {
            get
            {
                return this.zipField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.zipField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string country
        {
            get
            {
                return this.countryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.countryField = value;
            }
        }...you get the idea, it's too long to post here.
```

The Web Api Help Page shows a sample of the acceptable XML input which looks like this:

```
<order xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Models">
  <data>
    <shipments>
      <shipment>
        <giftnote />
        <products>
          <lineitem>
            <attributes>
              <attribute>
                <id>64</id>
              </attribute>
            </attributes>
            <description />
            <images>
              <orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
                <no>64</no>
                <url>sample string 1</url>
              </orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
              <orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
                <no>64</no>
                <url>sample string 1</url>
              </orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
              <orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
                <no>64</no>
                <url>sample string 1</url>
              </orderDataShipmentsShipmentProductsLineitemImage>
            </images>
            <mc_order />
            <number>64</number>
            <quantity>64</quantity>
            <sku>sample string 2</sku>
          </lineitem>
        </products>
        <shipattributes />
        <shippinginfo>
          <address1>sample string 2</address1>
          <address2 />
          <city>sample string 4</city>
          <country>sample string 7</country>
          <emailAddress>sample string 9</emailAddress>
          <method>64</method>
          <name>sample string 1</name>
          <phone />
          <shipCharge>11</shipCharge>
          <state>sample string 5</state>
          <zip>6</zip>
        </shippinginfo>
      </shipment>
    </shipments>
  </data>
  <header>
    <OriginalNumber />
    <billinginfo>
      <address1>sample string 2</address1>
      <address2 />
      <cc>
        <amt>sample string 4</amt>
        <ccv>sample string 3</ccv>
        <exp>sample string 2</exp>
        <number>sample string 1</number>
      </cc>
      <city>sample string 4</city>
      <country>sample string 7</country>
      <emailAddress>sample string 9</emailAddress>
      <name>sample string 1</name>
      <phone>8</phone>
      <state>sample string 5</state>
      <zip>6</zip>
    </billinginfo>
    <customerClient>
      <id>sample string 1</id>
    </customerClient>
    <customerOrderNumber>sample string 2</customerOrderNumber>
    <date>sample string 1</date>
    <number>sample string 3</number>
    <organization>
      <id>64</id>
    </organization>
    <status>
      <id>64</id>
    </status>
  </header>
</order>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class LegacyOrdersController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly ILegacyOrderRepository repository = new LegacyOrderRepository();

        public HttpResponseMessage PostOrder([FromBody]order order) <--this is null
        {
            order = repository.Add(order);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<order>(HttpStatusCode.Created, order);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = order.header.customerOrderNumber });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue here is with the order of Xml elements...note the difference in where the `<header>` tag is placed in your original xml and the helppage generated xml...Helppage generates that xml using web api's built-in Xml formatter which in turn (by default) uses `DataContractSerializer(DCS)`...with attributes like `DataContract` which DCS understands, you can order the elements in a specific manner...however i am not sure if DCS will honor attributes like  `XmlElement` to order...OR you could probably use `XmlSerializer` within web api xml formatter..

Comment: I saw that too and wasn't sure why it does that. Can you explain further how to use the XmlSerializer to accomplish this?

Comment: you can enable xml serializer in webapi by doing `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;`

Comment: Paste as XML generates some ugly code.  You could start small and code your model by hand to match xml piece by piece until it works.  It will be time consuming, but your model will be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started your paste operation using the wrong XML.  Take the XML generated from the web API help page and use that.  You will notice that the generated classes have the order of elements different than the code generated from your original XML.

Also to simplify the incoming XML you could configure to use XmlSerializer as shown from another stackoverflow post ([Serializer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068288/model-always-null-on-xml-post))

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

I also added `[Serializable]` to all of the generated classed buy I am not sure if that is actually needed.