# Post a collection to ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, collections

How should I post a collection of objects to a WEB API Rest service?

This is what I have in my Rest service..

I am using XmlSerializer

Here is the ActionMethod

```
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost]
public void PushToDb([FromBody] device[] devices)
{
    var iCount = devices.Count();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here is the device DTO:

```
public class device
{
    public string serialnumber { get; set; }
    public string hw_part_id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Request:

http://localhost:50384/api/Devices/PushToDb

And the XML input

```
<devices>    
    <device        
        <serialnumber>1</serialnumber>        
        <hw_part_id>A</hw_part_id>    
    </device>    
    <device>        
        <serialnumber>2</serialnumber>        
        <hw_part_id>A</hw_part_id>    
    </device>
</devices>
```

Content-Type is set as application/xml.

When I send this Post request, devices is always null. But if I change the Action method to just accept one device, I am able to receive the device data in the Action method.
Only when I am passing a collection I am not able to receive the input in the Action method.
Am I missing something? What should I do to be able to post a collection (XML input) to ASP.NET Rest service?

Thanks in advance.

Rag

Comment: Post via code? You can use WebClient.

Comment: Add DataContract and DataMember attributes to your DTO

Comment: just checking, "<device" doesn't have a closing ">"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068288/model-always-null-on-xml-post

Comment: Hi, device is closed properly. I just missed it here in the question. I added DataContract and DataMember to DTO and still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment decorate your class this way

```
[DataContract]
public class device
{
    [DataMember]
    public string serialnumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string hw_part_id { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (or any other library) to serialize an array of `device` type to json. and use [`System.Net.WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this way:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
     client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
     var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourArray); //yourArray is a device[]
     client.UploadString(ApiServiceUrl, jsonObj);

 }
```

Comment: `[DataContract]` & `[DataMember]` attributes are redundant. no?

Comment: He's requesting XML, which is similar.

Comment: Sorry. I added DataContract and DataMember and I still get null inside the action method.

Answer (score 0):

dear take a small break from work and watch this **MVA Course**, it will definitely solve your problem

https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/web-api-design-jump-start-8689?l=BMxSvaH1_3804984382

thank you