# XML deserialization from request body in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to setup an MVC app that has an endpoint that accepts XML in the request body, and then processes it.  I've dumbed this down to try and narrow down the problem, so here is my model:

```
Public Class MyModel
    Public Property Value1 As String
    Public Property Value2 As String
End Class
```

And I have this setup in my controller:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function Launch(<FromBody()> ByVal myModel As MyModel) As ActionResult
    ' ...
    ' myModel is always a new object but with null properties
    ' ...
End Function
```

And here is the HTTP request I'm sending:

```
POST /launch HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml

<MyModel>
    <Value1>1</Value1>
    <Value2>2</Value2>
</MyModel>
```

When I debug, it hits the correct endpoint but `myModel` is always empty.  And by empty I mean the object has been instantiated, but all the properties of it are `null`.

I've searched all over stackoverflow for an answer, and nothing has worked.  I have added `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = True` in the `Global.asax` code but that didn't seem to work.  I've also added a custom `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` that ignores xml namespaces which doesn't seem to do anything either.

Is there something blatantly obvious that I'm missing?  I know I'm using VB.NET and all the examples I've seen are C#, so maybe something was lost in translation.  At this point I'm having a hard time understanding why this is so hard to do.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps you are missing the data contract / xmls attribute in your XML post? `<MyModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppName.NameSpaceName"> ... </MyModel>`

Comment: Just found this solid SO answer -- I think the options presented might be worth a shot:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069824/7902641

Comment: @TylerCrawford yea I came across that answer before I posted my question.  I've already tried all of those options and none of them worked :\

Comment: One recommendation I have is to check the *actual* content you transmit, by using a "network sniffer" program, like Fiddler. Chances are your "body" is wrong. *Update*: Fiddler will only do the trick, if your client is a browser. Otherwise you would need something more sophisticated, like Wireshark.

Comment: @johannes.colmsee I'm using Postman to send the request, so I know exactly what is in the body.  I also double checked in Fiddler and it looks correct.

Comment: What about that "ByVal" thingy - I quickly googled it, and it seems to be basically the "ref" keyword of C#...if it is, don't do this ;)

Comment: @johannes.colmsee no, `ByVal` is the equivalent in VB to not putting `ref` in C#.  If you want to pass something by reference in VB, you would put `ByRef`.  It has to be passed `ByVal` or else it throws an error

Comment: I replicated your example, in C#...however - I used .Netcore WebAPI project. After I added the XmlSerializers in the startup it worked flawless. Before that - only JSON worked. How about JSON - does your code work with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169703/discussion-between-johannes-colmsee-and-jtate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because my controller was of type `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and not `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.  MVC controllers do not have the same deserialization abilities that WebAPI controllers have, and thus expect either JSON data or HTML form data as the payload.  After changing the class of the controller to `System.Web.Http.ApiController` it worked.