# Receive xml parameter in Restful API C#

Tags: c#, xml

i'm using Restful API C# and I tried to read xml parameter from client, but it turn out always null, heres my code:

```
[HttpPost("GPS")]
public IActionResult GPS( Document body)
{
    string strReturn="";
    return Ok(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
}

public class Document
{
    public string XML { get; set; }
}
```

heres my xml:

```
<ROOT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <USERID></USERID>
    <testing1>1</testing1>
</ROOT>
```

anyone can help, thanks

Comment: Is that data in file or Xml structure?

Comment: `Restful API` doesn't mean anything. Is this a *Web API* project? ASP.NET Core? In Web API and .NET Core you have to add the XML formattter explicitly.  ASP.NET MVC and the older WCF Rest supported XML by default.

Comment: BTW the `api` tag's description says "Don't Use". API doesn't mean REST or HTTP. It's any programming interface. Add a tag that specifies the stack you use

Comment: You open an element `<testing1>` but close a different element `</testing>`  so you have badly formed xml. You probably get an error saying so.

Comment: it's xml structure. i'm using .net core, i've already add xmlformater  
            services.AddMvc(config => {
                config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
                config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
             
            });
            services.AddMvc(Options=>{
                Options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            });
        }

Comment: Unless your XML is well formed, it will not be parsed correctly by an XML parser.
This is not well formed. `<testing1>1</testing>` because you open with testing**1** but close without the `1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting you have to pass the object like below

```
{
"XML": "<ROOT xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'> <USERID></USERID><testing1>1</testing></ROOT>"

}
```

After that you have to parse input string to XML to do your operation.

Or

Can you try below links. Might be helpful
https://forums.asp.net/t/2017239.aspx?Web+API+Posting+xml+as+string+always+post+null+on+the+server

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069824/4433080

Comment: Means the method parameter "body" is always getting NULL. Right?

Comment: correct,.. always get null. it seem only xml always get null, i tried to parse json no problem

Comment: thank you for your respon, in your answer in seem need global.asax to set xml, i dont have any global.asax, i only got startup.cs, i've already set xml to 
                services.AddMvc()
                    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
            
            services.AddMvc(Options=>{
                Options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            });

Comment: Have you tried my second link(stackoverflow). That is mainly discussing a problem similar to yours.

Comment: yes i already tried, herec my startup.cs
            services.AddMvc(config => {                config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());                config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());            });
            services.AddMvc(Options =>        {
                    Options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;                 Options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", "text/xml");
             Options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", "application/xml");                }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();