# How to use asp.net web API for accepting a HTTP POST containing XML?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use the Web API and accept a HTTP POST containing an XML.

I was under the impression that this could be automatically deserialized into an object, but I am missing something.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

This one works, I receive the XML from SoapUI and can act upon it

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Item() { Value = id });
    return response;
}
```

I'd like to have this though:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody]List<Item> items)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Trying to post this:

```
<Items><Item><Value>1</Value></Item></Items>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it always you find the answer right after posting.

I forgot to add:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

as mentioned on [AspNet WebApi POST parameter is null when sending XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142702/aspnet-webapi-post-parameter-is-null-when-sending-xml)

The XML I am sending looks like this now:

```
<ArrayOfItem><Item><Value>1</Value></Item><Item><Value>2</Value></Item></ArrayOfItem>
```

Can't remember where I read that it had to be specified as `ArrayOfXxx`